# Note Management Tool

Tags: linux

I am running [Linux Mint 18.3](https://linuxmint.com/) and am looking for an equivalent of [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/) for Linux (Yes, I know TagSpaces runs on Linux, too).

Ideally, I am looking for something quite similar to [TaskWarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/), but for notation - that being:

1. Have a tag function, to allow categorization;
2. Have a filter view, or a method to search for simple tags;

Rather basic, right?

I *would* use Google Keep if it was an offline client (hate working out of a web browser, it's not for me) and had a better filter mechanic (although, their search works well) - however I am investigating [this](https://github.com/andrepolischuk/keep).

Tools like [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) however as far as I am aware, these do not run native on Linux- plus, they want to charge me (hosting is not necessary, local is fine).

Comment: I almost feel bad for upvoting your reputation score of exactly 1000! Anyway, does it matter whether it's a GUI application to e.g. paste pictures?

Comment: Would something like [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com) work for you? It is browser based but is totally offline

Comment: @Luc CLI works perfectly fine - most notes currently are used via `nano`.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I will look at this when possible. If it meets requirements please make it an answer; even if I personally do not use it, someone else may benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com) has great tagging abilities and builtin search functionality.

Besides basic note taking it acts as a small application of sorts, allowing for scripting and extending its capabilities.

It is browser based but can run totally offline locally, from a single file or from a Node.js server instance if desired.